# How do I Control a computer App with Arduino input? (Specifically the scrollbar)

Tags: java, c#, arduino

Question:
How would I create a custom control in C# that would use input coming from an Arduino sensor and use that input to control the scrollbar on screen?

Example: 
A ribbon sensor is place on a window or sheet of glass with an LCD screen inside a box, using a bluetooth enabled connection the input would drive/move the scrollbar to move the text up and down. This is for an art installation where the screen itself cannot be touched.

I'm not sure if the example is helpful, but I thought I'd include it since it's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the Serial connection, that the Arduino already provides. .net provides a nice and easy to use serial library, which works in a similar fashion as the Arduino's. You can easily read and write to and from the serial port on your PC, interpret the commands sent from the Arduino and react accordingly.

Always make sure to close the serial monitor in your Arduino IDE before trying to connect with your .net program. Otherwise, your connection will be refused.